# My head keeps falling off. What can I do?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have an… *unusual* problem.

[image: What's my head doing over there?]

What?  How'd it happen?  No, no, that isn't impor—  Okay, fine.  It *might* have something to do with the `tim` command, a bandit chieftan, and an accident with an ebony greatsword.  But that's all you're getting out of me!

Now where was I?  Ah, yes.  Wherever I go, my head seems to be a few steps behind me, catching up at odd intervals only to be left behind again.  I just stopped to mine a corundum deposit, and my head fell to the ground and started rolling down the mountain!  *Very* embarrassing.

How can I fix this?  I was actually wandering around without any head at all for a while, but was able to restore it by `sexchange`ing twice.  Sadly, it doesn't appear to have been bolted on properly when it reappeared.  I can't even hide my deformity with a hat!

I'm making my [medical records](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12962279/StackExchange/Save%20124%20-%20Slitherskin%20%20Skyrim%20%2070.46.06.ess) available to anyone wishing to study my condition.

Comment: This is how you form a question.

Comment: Have you tried sewing it back on?

Comment: Put a bucket on your shoulders and call it a day? Everyone else in Skyrim is doing it!

Comment: Did the bandit chieftain preform a finishing move on you?

Comment: @Arkive — I honestly couldn't tell.  When using `tim`, you go into the third-person slo-mo cam every time you hit 0 health, so I'm not even sure if there's a difference to spot.  (Actually, I guess you wouldn't ask if there weren't, but either way I didn't see it.)  I didn't even notice the missing head until I stopped to mine some gold about 15 minutes later.

Comment: Maybe try having your head whacked back in place by a big dude wielding a giant mace? :p

Comment: This guy appears to have the same problem: `http://forums.somethingawful.com/showthread.php?threadid=3449362&userid=154601` You may have to wait for a save file editor.

Comment: @Arkive — That indeed looks like exactly the same problem.  At least I've haven't (yet) spent long enough in one cell to trigger the head-despawn crash.  Might get a bit dicey next time I'm in a dungeon, though.  :-/

Comment: I wonder what happens if your head rolls all the way down the mountain and crosses a loading zone :P

Comment: I believe you were decapitated and permanently registered as true since you get to continue to use your character after death.

Comment: Lesson: console-activated game modes meant for developer debugging-convenience aren't safe. But they *are* amusing.

Comment: Exact same thing is happening to me with same results on everything... i guess i shouldn't be lazy and level my armor this way....

Comment: Could it be possible that you share your save file with us? It should be in `\Documents\My Games\Skyrim\Saves`. Then it's more easy to test a bunch a things on it and come with a solution...

Comment: @Tom Wijsman — Hadn't even occurred to me.  There you go!

Comment: funny allright, but, too local..

Comment: @Bora If you mean localised to the neck, sure. Enough people are unwittingly walking into this bug though. God modes aren't usually this badly bugged!

Comment: God modes and console commands aren't meant to be used in-game in the first place.

Answer (score 66):

When you get killed by a decapitating strike, **a flag gets set in the game state** to denote that an animation should be played showing that you got decapitated. Upon loading the game; the animation of the body appears to be overridden by another animation (eg. your character wobbles even though your standing still), so the flag does not affect the body part. However, it does affect the head...

I see two ways to get rid of this annoying stuck flag:

1. <s>Get someone to do a decapitating strike on you without being in immortal mode.</s>

   <s>If lucky, the flag is removed upon death. If unlucky, it just adds and removes a second flag...</s>

   **Update:**
   The above fix won't work, once you get killed it will just reload the save game again. In a similar vein the other fixes mentioned in this question (and elsewhere) do not work because they do not clear the flag from the save game. Editing the save game seems to be a necessity to fix this.
2. Get two save games, the one right before and after the incident. It might be more feasible to try to reproduce this and get two save games in which there are less changes...

   Then, use Notepad++ to do a regular expression replace to change  `::` into `\n`.

   Now you can use WinDiff and set it to show right-only lines. If done properly the amount of changes would be minimal and if you look at the lines containing `_var` variables you could easily figure out which flag affects this. Replacing one character should yield the flag invalid, do however not add/remove characters as that might break the file.

Comment: I can't think of a way to tell whether I've been decapitated again and the saves are too far apart to be very helpful (about 7 hours of play; I'd just discovered Quick Save and got lazy), so I wasn't able to find a variable that did the trick.  I'm going to start a new character and see if I can't reproduce the problem so that I have a better test case.

Comment: @BenBlank: `set DecapitationChance to 100` and `set KillMoveRandom to 100` seem to ensure a decapitating blow is dealt to you, together with `tim` that should allow you to reproduce this behavior. I'm currently near a camp with multiple guards and a dragon in the air disallowing me from saving when I attack the group of guards, running too far away causes the game to crash and a quick save seems to get broken because I'm in a fight. So, I can't test this in the current situation but might try again at a later point where it would result in a smaller fight and I can kill the decapitators... :)

Comment: On your save game, I tried using `tim` and the above mentioned commands (also with low KillMoveRandom values as I'm unsure if it contributes to decapitation) till I received a decapitating blow; then, when I was down on the floor I used `tim` again in order for the game to see me as dead. Apparently that doesn't work as it just reloads the save game, I think the only thing left to do is obtaining two save games that consist of a minimal change in game state. Then do a manual or binary diff...

Comment: After trying for about an hour, with various values for `DecapitationChance` and `KillMoveRandom` as well as opponents, I can't seem to get a decapitation at all.  Who/what were you fighting and how were they armed when you managed it?

Comment: @BenBlank: I'm starting to think I never got decapitated by an enemy before... o_O Is there a cut scene supposed to happen when the enemy does that? Because I thought if they lift their weapon high in the sky and then knock me down on the floor it would be a decapitation, but now I'm starting to think that that different animation is just the kill move and not an actual decapitation. Have you tried a troll? Or a bandit chieftan like you mentioned in your question?

Comment: I've recreated the circumstances as best I can't but don't seem to be able to get a decapitation even without `tim`.  If I were a more paranoid man, I'd suspect 1.2 removed random decapitations.

Answer (score 22):

Have you tried werewolf transforming? That seems to re-initalize your body/race.

At the very last resort, you could do `showracemenu` and change nothing, but that [has side-effects](https://unofficialskyrimpatch.16bugs.com/projects/7078/bugs/209491).

Comment: Well, this gets me closer than anything yet.  Unlike `sexchange`, this not only causes my head to reappear, but also attaches it correctly.  Unfortunately, helm graphics still don't show and my head vanishes again when I exit and restart the game.  :-(

Comment: The werewolf change does not work. It is temporary fix, if you equip a helmet you will see that the player is bald. Also it does not work if you go to werewolf, sexchange, werewolf out, sexchange again. Also it does not work to change in ANY other animal and back to player. I have found that the game value is stuck at "islimbgone 1".The number 1 is the value for the model's head. I don't know the command to force the game to reload the player model.

Answer (score 16):

I've got the same problem and [I posted about this](http://forums.bethsoft.com/index.php?/topic/1313310-immortal-mode-decapitation-glitch/page__pid__19747639#entry19747639) on the Bethesda Forums about a week ago. There a kindly young chap dropped me with some wisdom, although not entirely helpful, it was a piece of the puzzle. He claimed that this problem had been posted before, and said the sexchange was necessary, but that I also needed to 'remove gory neck graphic'.

He said this problem can be fixed in console by typing in the following:

```
sexchange
sexchange
player.removeitem 000DB5D0 1
sexchange
sexchange
```

Comment: Can you link to your forum post?  I'm digging into this now.  :-)

Comment: Here's the original post: http://forums.bethsoft.com/index.php?/topic/1313310-immortal-mode-decapitation-glitch/page__pid__19747639#entry19747639                                                                                               There should be a link to Shazbit's "common bug fixes" thread at the end of one of his posts. He still hasn't found the id for it from what I've read.

Comment: I'm sorry, not Shazbit, the other gentleman in the thread, "noodlesdefyyou".

Comment: I've been futzing around with this, but if the "gory neck" / "gorey stump" item exists, it doesn't show when using `player.showinventory` — I've emptied the list without fixing the problem.

Comment: Ben! I've found the id in question. The previous format should work, and put this: "player.removeitem 000DB5D0 1" instead of the 'remove gory neck id'. Safe travels, sir.

Comment: Interesting!  This does indeed seem to have removed my neck stump — I can now see the inside of my armor by looking into the neck hole — but it didn't reattach my head.

Answer (score 9):

Change into a werewolf then change back!

Use these console commands to gain the werewolf abilities if you haven't gotten them in game yet.

```
player.addspell 00092c48
player.addspell 000a1a3e
```

Change then change back. Once you are done use these console commands to go back to normal.

```
player.removespell 00092c48
player.removespell 000a1a3e
```

Just don't do it in town or near anyone else!

Answer (score 3):

Based on your comments,  `tim` = toggle immortal mode. A thief and an ebony broadsword.  Did you die and then make yourself immortal or something? If that's the case, maybe you're still dead? Have you tried `resurrect`ing yourself? Might try `player.resurrect`. But I'm just guessing what's going on here. Pure guess. Nothing concrete to back it up. Mostly cause my head is still attached.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't reattach my head so much as it *crashes the game*.  Interesting idea, though.  :-)

Comment: `tim` wouldn't have any effect if he was already dead. All it does is negate the damage from any hit which would inflict enough damage to kill you - but this is apparently independent of the "would you die?" check used to trigger finishing moves, so they still go through, causing potentially... unusual results.

Comment: This isn't a final answer to the question, it should be a comment.