# Resurrecting a follower with items that cannot be picked up

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

I'm playing the Dawnguard DLC now and I've gotten the Ultimate Followers Overhaul and Deadly Dragons Mod. I have 2 followers currently. They are Serana and Faendal.

Now I've equipped Faendal with a giant club (found in one of the giant camps). The player cannot pick the club but if you target your companion to pick it up, he does that with success and that's what I've done with Faendal.

The club deals 111 (or so) damage and I really don't want to lose it. Is there any way that I could respawn Faendal with items if he dies?

Comment: you might have better luck just to spawn an instance of the item with placeatme and telling Faendal to pick it up again.

Comment: @z' Yes, that's a pretty good idea too. But any commands for the current solution?

Comment: Why not [set the follower to be essential](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50604/in-skyrim-the-console-command-to-set-a-follower-as-essential-is-not-working-wh)? If he can't die, you won't need to resurrect him.

Answer (score 1):

Open the console then type the following 5 line in order (pressing enter after each line):

```
prid 0001348C
moveto player
disable
enable
resurrect
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are still near his corpse, I believe selecting it in the console and using console command `resurrect` revives followers with all of their items. It's been a while and I can't test it at the moment, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Given that he's not dead yet, the easiest way of all is to open the console and type `setessential 13480 1` to make him essential (that number is the BaseID, according to [UESP](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Faendal); leading zeros are *not* required, and you can look up other BaseIDs with `help <NPC name>`).  This will prevent him from dying in the first place.  There are other ways to make the player or an NPC immortal, but the essential flag is by far the most reliable and safe way to accomplish it (in particular, it will [prevent your head from falling off](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/37805/91981)).

Alternatively, give the club to Serana instead of Faendal, because she is already essential.